# Enterprise custom field value using SharePoint API

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, project-server, ms-project-server-2010

Is it possible to get project's enterprise custom field value using SharePoint 2010 API?

Comment: Why do you need sharepoint api for this? You have PSI services for this.

Comment: I have existing WCF service hosted in SharePoint (ISAPI) and I thought using SP API would be the best approach (the easiest way to get data). Should I use PSI?

Comment: Well, Project Server has its own data structure and you cannot access it from SharePoint API. You have to use Project Server PSI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Project Server has its own data structure and you cannot access it from SharePoint API. You have to use Project Server PSI.

Comment: Is it possible to get project custom field by name or I have to use guid?

Comment: You can try to use CustomFields service to get custom field (for example ReadCustomFields with xmlFilter) and then get GUID from it and use it.